# How can I fix vscode syntax and validation error on a xml file with a custom xsd schema

Tags: xml, validation, xsd, visual-studio-code, redhat

**Good day everyone,**

Can someone help me with this issue.

I created a custom xsd schema for an xml file. Am using Vscode with red Hat xml extension to help me bind the schema to all my xml files in my workspace.

The schema works for only the top elements but not on the nested elements in the xml file.

Here is an example of my issue.

[image]

I will really appreciate it if some can help me solve this problem in vscode. Thank

Answer (score 0):

This was [fixed](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-xml/issues/66) in vscode-xml 0.2.0, now available in the [VS Code Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.vscode-xml).